# Why am I not receiving a DHCPOFFER, RaspberriPi, DHCP, Linux

Tags: dhcp

Current setup are 2 "RaspberriPi 3" models

**On the first one I am trying to establish an ad-hoc network with the following commands**

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc
iwconfig wlan0 essid RPInet
ifconfig wlan0 10.0.0.200 netmask 255.255.255.0
/usr/sbin/dhcpd wlan0
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo wlan0
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server

```
INTERFACES="wlan0"
```

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
DHCPDARGS=wlan0;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
option domain-name "RPi-Network";
option routers 10.0.0.1;
authoritative;

subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.20;
}
```

**On the second RPi I want to use wpa_supplicant and dhclient to obtain a lease from the first one**

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/example.conf
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet manual
auto lo wlan0
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant/example.conf

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="RPInet"
}
```

**Why is RPI 2 not obtaining an IP address from the DHCP?**

**Another question: Why is the DHCP not going into active state after using /usr/sbin/dhcp wlan0 ?**

[Raspberr Pi 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTOkn.png)

[RaspberryPi 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMlsd.png)

The dhcpdiscover and offer in syslog from pi 1 are from itself. the mac address is its own, so why does it send itself requests?

Comment: which channel are your pis connected on? do the channels match when you do `iwconfig wlan0` on both Pis?

Comment: 2.412 Ghz the first one, none on the second. Both iwconfigs are in the pictures below my post.

Comment: can you fix your Rpis `iwconfig` as 

`sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc channel 1 essid RPinet` this can majorly solve problems at times.

if you want some help I have written a blogpost [here](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/147699665389/ad-hoc-networking-with-raspberry-pis)

Comment: on the first one i used `iwconfig wlan0 channel 1` and I configured wpasupplicant on the other one to `ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant ctrl_interface_group=root update_config=1 ap_scan 2 network={ssid="RPi" scan_freq=2412 scan_ssid=1 key_mgmt=NONE mode=1 priority=1}` when starting it and starting wpa_cli it says `trying to associate with SSID "RPi", Association request to the driver failed`

Comment: when I use `iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc iwconfig wlan0 essid RPi and ifconfig wlan0 10.0.0.201 netmask 255.255.255.0 up` I can ping the first one on 10.0.0.200 successfully

Comment: okay. Let me write a  proposed solution for you and then you can give me some feedback. also what distribution are you using ? Jessie or Wheezy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read through your Logs which you have posted for your Pis.

Here are some bits that I would like to point out:

1. I am really not sure if you should be using really high `txpower`. Yours is `31 dBm` which is extremely high. Chances are that this signal might cause a lot of interference on the channel if there is some wireless activity going on.
   I suggest you reduce it something like `10 to 15 dBm` this is an acceptable value.
2. Also if you are using **Edimax 7811UN** adapters and using **Raspbian Wheezy** with versions less than **7.10/7.11** then there will definitely be an incompatibility issue, since the older **Raspbian versions** did cause a lot of problems when running the **Edimax** in ad-hoc mode. (I did some experiments and this was evident for me). However in **Raspbian Jessie** or **Wheezy 7.10 and 7.11** this compatibility driver issue is resolved and the adapters work in ad-hoc mode
3. If you are not receiving any **DHCP** offers chances are likely that your Pis are on two different frequencies of the spectrum. I strongly suggest creating a small bash function in your `/etc/rc.local` where you atleast set initial `iwconfig` parameters the same.

   ```
    createNetwork(){
              ifconfig wlan0 down
              iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc essid RpiNet channel 1
              ifconfig wlan0 up
    }
    createNetwork
    exit 0
   ```
4. One more thing is that not a lot of people realize that appropriate channel selection for WLAN is really important. You should definitely first do a scan/sweep on your vicinity and see which Routers or hot spots are using the same channels. Do a `iwlist wlan0 scanning` and go through all the channels and chose an appropriate channel for your ad-hoc network

> I have a white-paper which proposes that in order to have minimal interference among the WLAN channels selection of **Channels 1, 6, 11** are the best. For instance, if you scan and find channel 1 and 11 occupied it is suggested to use Channel 6 to avoid interference.

### Comprehensive Look

Create a setup function in your `/etc/rc.local` like follows:

```
 # network connectivity..
 createNetwork(){

          ifconfig wlan0 down
          iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc essid Pi-Net txpower 10 dBm channel 6
          ifconfig wlan0 up
 }

 createNetwork

 exit 0
```

Your DHCP server settings look right to me. Maybe do something like auto enable on reboot of the Pi

```
   sudo systemctl enable dhcpcd.service # For Jessie
```

or

```
   sudo update-rc.d isc-dhcp-server enable # For Wheezy
```

This is what I can make of from your situation. I suggest getting updated to Jessie or atleast Wheezy 7.10/7.11 for proper functioning of Ad-Hoc networking.

Also one thing is switch off your `power-management` of your WiFi dongle in order to avoid making your dongle sleep when Idle.

```
  iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

This solution is based on the assumptions of your situation, and the best of my knowledge to help you solve it through

Comment: It now works without using wpa_supplicant at all. All I am using is `iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc`, `iwconfig wlan0 essid RPi` and `dhclient -1 wlan0`. With just those commands I am able to receive an IP from DHCP. Thank you very much! I will have a look into power ratio and channel selection, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Is that a good thinG?

Comment: desirably I would have wanted wpasupplicant to set the parameters and connect, but this will be just fine

Comment: All I am wondering now is why `/usr/sbin/dhcp wlan0` command wont start DHCP. When checking status it tells me it is in "inactive". So I use `service isc-dhcp-server restart` and it becomes active...

Comment: chances are you `dhcp` might not be right executable available on the Pi. I was also once confused as to which dhcp service was to be used `isc-dhcp-server` or `dhcpcd` configuration. I am sure a little research would get the answer on the table.